# Include post data from a second form when submitting

Tags: python, django, forms, post

I am working on a django template that includes two forms. Lets call the first one main and the second one sub. I want to be able to submit main and get the post data from sub with it. Sub contains options for main and I need to be able to change main and re-select similar options from sub.

I have everything set up to the point that I can get the post data from main but I can't figure out how to include sub. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django comes with an optional “form wizard” application that splits forms across multiple Web pages. It maintains state in one of the backends so that the full server-side processing can be delayed until the submission of the final form.

Read the official docs here: [Form Wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/).

Comment: This could possibly work for what I'm trying to do. I will look into it and report back. Thanks!